# BigQuery: Append to table from select with nested record ('Insert into tablename select')

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi is there a way to append the selected result with a nested column into an existing table?

BigQuery seems not to support 'insert into tablename select...' so i tried it over the .net-api. It works fine but if my select contains a nested record i will get the **error** (with or without flatten-result-flag):

**'Field Products from table oxidation.2016_91 is not a leaf field. '**

The tableschema for this column in the destination table is the same.

It seems only to work if i write out the column Name in the nested column, but i want to have the destination table structure to stay the same.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If schemas the same, below should work

[image]

Comment: You can also use `SELECT UserId, Products.* FROM [...]`, which would filter out any extra fields that * would catch.